# What could cause a sudden ClassNotFoundException in a long running process?

Tags: java, jvm, noclassdeffounderror, classnotfoundexception

We have a very small Web service (less than 1K lines of code) which is run by Jetty. The service worked always fine even during our stress testing phase. However, after 13 days of uptime we experienced a ClassNotFoundException in two nodes the same day.

The strange thing is that *the class that wasn't found was already there (it is part of the startup routine and it was used constantly servicing previous requests)*. In fact, simply restarting the process solved the issue. Both nodes are in separate machines and are independent of each other. They don't depend on external resources, except on one JMS connection.

I couldn't find relevant information while Googling this, as most of the reported issues are related to missing classes in the class path while starting up the Java process, which is not our case. We suspect there could be a memory leak that in a way corrupted the JVM memory, however this can't explain why the same problem happened in two nodes around the same time. We've been running intensive stress testing during the last five days attaching a JVM monitor and a memory leak analyzer, and everything seems fine. For this tests we decreased the process memory from 2GB to 512MB.

**Details:**

- Using Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.3-b01, mixed mode)
- Using jetty-runner-8.1.0.RC5.jar
- Original cmd line: java -Xmx2048M -jar jetty-runner-8.1.0.RC5.jar --port 5000 webapp.war
- Intel Xeon E5-2680 8 cores (x2) + 16GB RAM
- Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6
- Some frameworks in use: JBoss Resteasy, Spring IoC, Guava.

Can you please contribute with ideas regarding what could make the JVM to suddenly "forget" about the existence of a previously loaded class, not being able to load it again?

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.a.b.c.SomeClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:377) ~[na:na]
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:95) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:107) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:31) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseSig(AnnotationParser.java:370) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseClassValue(AnnotationParser.java:351) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseMemberValue(AnnotationParser.java:280) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(AnnotationParser.java:222) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(AnnotationParser.java:69) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(AnnotationParser.java:52) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Field.java:1014) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getDeclaredAnnotations(Field.java:1007) ~[na:1.6.0_37]
```

**Edit:**

Someone mentioned me that while using NFS mounts under Win, it could happen that the JVM decides to unload a class, and then re-loads it when it's needed. If in the middle of this process the NFS connection was broken, the file handle will be invalid and the re-loading will fail with a similar stacktrace. In our case, we are using Linux and all the involved files are in the same mount, which is a local hard disk. Just for the sake of more testing, I've CD'd into the Jetty temporary directory and manually deleted one well known for one specific service class. If the JVM unloads it and then attempts to re-load it from the classes directory, it will fail. While this does not explain the original problem, it might put more information on the table...

Comment: do you have more lines in your stacktrace ? could be due to some instances trying to modify dynamically the classpath of your webapp container.

Comment: @Farid: yes. The lines above are related to a Jackson deserializer that failed to load a class (which name I have obfuscated as com.a.b.c.SomeClass for confidentialy reasons). For the same reason, I can't copy-paste it. However I will soon edit the question adding more information. Thanks,

Comment: most of the projects I'm working on also use jackson, but never had any issues like you had. The only difference I can see is that we usually use tomcat instead of jetty, and I never use annotations for jackson. Do you think you could give it a try under a tomcat instance to discard any classpath modification mecanism from jetty, or without any annotations for jackson (since your app is a small one)?

Comment: One I can think of is hot deployment scanner, ie jetty detects there's a change on your app files and reload the whole classpath. Disable this feature if you're using it

Comment: The main question is still why the class is loaded again? Did you disabled hot deployment as @gerrytan suggested?

Comment: A related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12399089/classes-missing-if-application-runs-for-a-long-time

Comment: Hot deployment was never enabled. We found out the problem relies on disappearing directories on /tmp (see below).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is what is happening:

1. When the service is started using the cmd detailed above, Jetty creates a sub-dir under the "/tmp", which holds the application classes and resources loaded by the JVM.
2. After a period of inactivity (in our specific scenario, between 13 and 20 days) that directory disappears. As a result, the JVM can't load the file. We still don't know precisely if the JVM unloaded the class before this error, or why it tried to re-read the *.class file. It would be interesting to look into the source code and learn about this, but that's not in our short-term ToDo list.
3. Simply restarting Jetty caused the missing directories to be recreated, and the service is up again.

A good hint we had is that some people reported a similar issue while loading resources in JARs over NFS on Windows (if network connectivity is lost for a brief moment, NFS handles become invalid and the JVM fails with a similar error). This is not our case (/tmp is local storage), but quite similar.

Thanks everyone for their help.

Comment: Thanks to you, we were able to fix a very similar bug on our Jetty 9 servers. In our case, the server runs on CentOS distribution where there is a daily cron job that cleans up the files in the `/tmp` directory if they haven't been accessed in 10 days. We can fix this by simply creating a directory called `work` under Jetty home and restarting the server by doing which, Jetty will not use `/tmp` to explode the WAR files.

Comment: this is happening (we think) on bootable Wildfly as well, since it also makes heavy use of `/tmp`.   it happens after a long period of usage, and restarting the process immediately fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace tells us that it is about processing annotations and not connected with loading the class for executing code. It seems that the annotation processor tries to resolve the *value* of an annotation member through the `ClassLoader` of the annotated element.

In other words you have an annotation with a value of class type like `@Foo(xyz=ABC.class)` and a class or member annotated with this construct but the class `ABC` is not reachable through the `ClassLoader` of the annotated element at runtime.

This does not conflict with the fact that this class has already been loaded through another `ClassLoader`.

Comment: It sounds a little bit strange. How you explain this that the problem occurs only after long time, about 13 days as you wrote?

Comment: I don’t know much about the EE-framework/webservice’s `ClassLoader` structure and activities. Is there a reloading/redeployment involved?

Comment: I think that the major case in which there is any reloading/ redeployment is when you have hot deployment enabled and some resources change, but I assume that this is not this case here and that you switched off hot deployment as @gerrytan suggested in comments. I assume you are using this jetty configuration only for development and not for later tests and not for production?