# NoClassDefFoundError on previously operational function

Tags: java, scala, akka

I have a server process that crashed with a NoClassDefFoundError (copied below). I have searched for causes of this, and the given answers (usually path related) don't seem consistent with what I experienced (typically the OP experienced this problem immediately upon first run). In my case, this particular process had been running for a month+ without incident calling this same function that suddenly 'became undefined'. What might cause this to suddenly break?

Two scenarios I am entertaining is either 1) some sort of memory issue, either overflow or inability to load a jar into memory, or 2) some sort of program corruption, like if a command was made to recompile the program which was aborted mid-build which resulted in a bad jar, or even if it completed it broke some sort of versioning/linking. This is heavy conjecture and am hoping somebody with a better understanding of the java JVM (and how scala compiles down to java?) could confirm or reject the plausability of either of these scenarios.

```
Uncaught error from thread [moosetracks-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-61633] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[moosetracks]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: UsersManager$$anonfun$listDestinations$1
        at UsersManager.listDestinations(moosetracks.scala:872)
        at AdminActor.routeJson(moosetracks.scala:1139)
        at AdminActor.adminRequest(moosetracks.scala:1244)
        at AdminActor$$anonfun$receive$6.applyOrElse(moosetracks.scala:1027)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:262)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:975)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1478)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:104)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: UsersManager$$anonfun$listDestinations$1
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 13 more
```

Comment: Looks like a library was deleted from your environment. Review all libraries (jars) in the classpath of your applications.

Comment: That could make sense if I had both my production and dev terminals open and accidentally ran the build command in the wrong terminal, yes? Is there a way to tell a JVM to retain linked jars in memory to protect against (this admittedly preventable) scenario?

Comment: The jars would be unloaded after undeploying the application, so it would be better if you define some security permissions on your classpath to prevent deletion of elements (in this case, jars) unless you're root user.

Comment: So, if the jar file was modified after the process had been started, it should not have affected the running process?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Unless you redeploy the application in that moment and this jar is shared by other libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a similar question some time ago where I [noticed that OOM can produce this symptom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12404984/1296806).

That was not a definitive diagnosis in that case. Class unloading was not verified.

Both scenarios include some notion of "long-running".

You say "previously operational function," but maybe you mean `listDestinations` and not the code path requiring the anonymous function.